# MDX custom period parsing out

Tags: mdx

I´m trying to create a measure to divide the time dimension into periods, but the Parser just keeps...parsing. Here´s the attempted member:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Period] AS  
CASE  
   WHEN [Registerdate].[Registerdate].Currentmember.MEMBERVALUE <
   "2016-02-15T00:00:00" THEN ('Inreg Per 2016-01') 
   /.../ 
   ELSE ('Period not mapped') 
END
```

Any advice welcome. Thank you in advance.
/M

Comment: Make sure the value property of this attribute is set to a date column with a date data type.

Comment: When you say "...but the Parser just keeps...parsing" do you mean that it never returns an answer to you? Without the rest of the mdx script it is impossible for anyone to help you - can you please add the whole script?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I managed to get past the eternal parsing, but now the various periods are not recognized by the comparison operator. Instead every date is mapped as 'Period not mapped'. DataType is Date. As for the reminder of the code it is simply Select [Measures].[Period] On 0, [Registerdate].[RegisterWeek].CHILDREN On 1 From [MyCube]